# Remove [ "" : from mongoDb result using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

To remove the "_id" from the mongo result I use :

```
DBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
DBObject removeIdProjection = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
data.addAll(collection.find(allQuery , removeIdProjection).toArray());
```

The results of this query is :

```
    { "" : { [ 

    {
    "test1" : "test1"
    {
   }]}
```

How to remove `{ "" :` so result is of format :

```
   [ 
    {
    "test1" : "test1"
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Which version of Mongo? Which version of the Java driver? What class is the object "collection"? What is "data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put result in json object which add extra brackets here.

`toArray()` converts type `cursor` to `list` so you need to store it in list. You can iterate this list to access elements. You should use following code to get expected result:

```
DBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
DBObject removeIdProjection = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
List cursor = collection.find(allQuery , emoveIdProjection).toArray();
System.out.println("result: " + cursor);
```